# how to get labels string for marker view in PieChart using Charts library

Tags: ios, charts

I'm using Charts library for iOS to create a pie chart. I've looked through the demo given and wanted to add a marker when the pie chart is selected.

Problem now is even though I can get the percentage value, I can't get the label string that the selected value represents. I'm using back the XYMarker file in the demo.

Here is my data entry code:

```
let type = ["Basic Commission", "BSC Bonus", "Overriding Commission", "Other Income"]
let value = [25, 10, 50, 15]

let entries = (0..<count).map { (i) -> PieChartDataEntry in
   return PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(value[i % value.count]),
                                 label: type[i % type.count])
}

let set = PieChartDataSet(values: entries, label: "")
```

And my XYMarker file is as follow:

```
public class XYMarkerView: BalloonMarker {

fileprivate var yFormatter = NumberFormatter()

public override init(color: UIColor, font: UIFont, textColor: UIColor, insets: UIEdgeInsets) {
    yFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
    yFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    yFormatter.multiplier = 1
    yFormatter.percentSymbol = " %"

    super.init(color: color, font: font, textColor: textColor, insets: insets)
}

public override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {

    let string = yFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: entry.y))!

    setLabel(string)
}}
```

Anyone can help get the label string?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import Charts

//Its Custom Class for Pie chart;

public class PieMarkerView: BalloonMarker {
  fileprivate var yFormatter = NumberFormatter()

public override init(color: UIColor, font: UIFont, textColor: UIColor, insets: UIEdgeInsets) {
    yFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
    yFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    super.init(color: color, font: font, textColor: textColor, insets: insets)
}

public override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {

    if (entry is PieChartDataEntry) {
        let pe = entry as! PieChartDataEntry
        let string = ""
            + pe.label!
            + "\n "
            + yFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: entry.y))!
        setLabel(string)
        return
    }else{
        let string = "x: "
            + String(entry.x)
            + ", y: "
            + yFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: entry.y))!
        setLabel(string)
    }


}

}
```

Add Above Custom Class for Pie chart marker View

```
//Pie chart MarkerView
        let marker = PieMarkerView(color: UIColor(white: 180/250, alpha: 1),
                                   font: UIFont(name: "open sans", size: 12)!,
                                   textColor: .white,
                                   insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 20, right: 8))
        marker.chartView = pieChart
        marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 40)
        pieChart.marker = marker
```